# Does MIMIC-III have carbohydrate intake information for patients?

Tags: mimic-iii

Does MIMIC-III have carbohydrate intake information for patients? If so, can you point out the corresponding tables?

I am interested in studying the relationship between carbs and glucose variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
select * from mimiciii.d_items where category LIKE '%Fluids%' order by label
```

This query lists all the 'Fluids' categories, and you will notice these link to `inputevents_mv` (this seems to only apply to the MetaVision subset).

There are various dextrose items. ItemId 220950 is dextrose 10%.

```
SELECT * FROM mimiciii.inputevents_mv where itemid = 220950 and icustay_id = 226105
```

shows administration of this for ICU stay 226105.

Dextrose (glucose derived from corn starch) seems to be the only parenterally-administered carbohydrate. There are also dextran, pentastarch and hetastarch, all of which are used as a 'plasma volume expander' (usually following severe bleeding), and mannitol which is an osmotic diuretic, and all of which are basically metabolically inert.

Comment: Is Dextros the only carbohydrate input to the patients in ICU?

Comment: Dextrose (glucose derived from corn starch) seems to be the only parenterally-administered carbohydrate. 
There are also dextran, pentastarch and hetastarch, all of which are used as a 'plasma volume expander' (usually following severe bleeding), and mannitol which is an osmotic diuretic, and all of which are basically metabolically inert.